# get pppd exit code - how?

Tags: shell-script, pppd, connectivity, exit-status

I'm designing some reporting system on Raspberry Pi system which connects to world thru 3G usb modem controlled by `pppd`.

99,999% of time connection works ok, but sometimes it drops and further reconnect attempts fail unless modem is re-plugged physically.

As in production box will work remotely with no physical access to it so I have to manage it somehow.

My idea is to run at system start, some kind of script in separate thread see below pseudocode:

```
while(true){
  wait_for_modem_device_to_appear
  start_pppd # may_be limiting retries not to default 10, but to, say, 3
  wait_for_pppd_to_finish
  if(exitcode_is_one_of(6,7,8,10,15,16)){
    reset_usb_port_programmatically #I have tools for that
  }else{
    break
  }
}
```

- How can I get `pppd` exit code?
- Should I use another approach (which)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bingo!**

Put 'nodetach' as command-line argument to pppd and daemon will not fork itself. All is needed then is standard 'echo $?'  in next line of script:

```
pppd call my_provider nodetach maxfail 3
echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling 'pppd' you need get value of variable '$?'.

`$?` - get exit code of last program.

For background processes '$!' may be useful with some cover.

`$!` - get PID of last background process that was executed.

Example scenario:

```
run_background_process &
pid_of_background_process=$!
wait $pid_of_background_process
echo "Result code of background process: "$?
```

Comment: Yury, ppd is running on background so you will get 0 always

Comment: @DmitryD, I've supplemented answer.

Comment: Solution you proposed doesn't work even with supplement, but thanks for your try!